# How to have ssh session inherit environment variables from sshd?

Tags: ssh

I have `sshd` set up in a remote host with bunch of environment variables set. Then I ssh'd into it and get the following with: `ps`

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0 112868  4208 ?        Ss   19:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e
root       127  0.0  0.0 148480  5372 ?        Ss   19:34   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root       129  0.0  0.0  13392  1892 pts/0    Ss   19:34   0:00 -bash
```

Current `pid` is `129`. Its parent is `127`, whose parent is `1`.

How do I get my current ssh session to have all environment variables from the initial `sshd` process? Both the current process and its parent don't have environment variables that are set in sshd.

Comment: Environment of sshd has nothing to do with environment of your ssh sessions. Look at the answers [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813)

Answer (score -2):

Actually SSH should have the default system environment variables.
This means that its variables should be from the following files: `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`. A lot of the variables are shell specific though;

Since you're using bash you'll automatically execute `/etc/bash.bashrc` and the user-specific login scripts upon shell creation.

To get the environment variables from those files, just execute them before running anything else.

Sources:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference
https://www.tecmint.com/set-unset-environment-variables-in-linux/